# Why does this cause a ClassCastException?

Tags: java

```
public class Test8 {
   public static void main (String args[]) {
      Number numberRef = new Integer(0);
      Double doubleRef = (Double)numberRef;
   }
}
```

It shows me exception at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
  java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Because `Integer` is not a sub-class of `Double`?

Comment: Yeah, can't cast `Integer` into `Double`. arshajii below has the right answer, use `doubleValue()`.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that Integer and int, Double and double are different things.

Comment: Some beginners tend to think that casting is some kind of conversion, but it's not. Casting is just telling the compiler "No, you think there's a chance this object may not be an instance of this class but I can assure you it will be, so try to compile it anyway". Needless to say, when at runtime the object is not an instance of the class you said it would be, a runtime exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to cast an instance of `Integer` to a reference `Double` which cannot happen. `Integer` and `Double` are two different classes and objects of each cannot be simply cast to each other

`Number` is a common `super` class for `Integer` and `Double`, hence an instance of `Double` or `Integer` can be *[upcasted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361999/whats-the-need-to-use-upcasting-in-java)* to  `Number`. In other words, `Integer` [IS A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Number`, `Double` [IS A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Number` BUT, `Integer` [IS NOT A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Double`

```
Integer i = new Integer(0);
Double d = new Double(1);
Number ni = i;
Number di = d;
Integer id = d; //invalid;
Double dd = i; //invalid
```

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving a `ClassCastException` in accordance with [JLS §5.5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.3):

> Here is the algorithm to check whether the run-time type `R` of an object is assignment compatible with the type `T` which is the erasure ([§4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)) of the type named in the cast operator. If a run-time exception is thrown, it is a `ClassCastException`.
>
> If `R` is an ordinary class (not an array class):
>
> - **If `T` is a class type, then `R` must be either the same class ([§4.3.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.4)) as `T` or a subclass of `T`, or a run-time exception is thrown.**
> - ...
>
> ...

Note that [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is *not* a subclass of [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).

---

What about

```
Double doubleRef = numberRef.doubleValue();
```

instead?

[`doubleValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue%28%29) is a method of the [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

`numberRef.doubleValue();` will return the double value of the Integer which could then be assigned to the Double

Documentation -

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html